# IOS/Objective-C: Exclude empty values

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

I thought I had seen every possible flavor of values for properties that have not been set in an object, but evidently I have not.

Basically, I want to exclude cases where a value has not been set for a string property of an `NSManagedObject`.  In fact, I want to exclude every case *except* where there is a valid string of 4 characters or more.

I was using the following code:

```
if (![contact.pic isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]&&contact.pic.length>4) {
           //I have a valid string
        }
        else {
            //I don't have valid string
        }
```

However, it is not excluding some values (most likely where a value was never set) where it logs the values to console as follows:

```
NSLog(@"contact.pic is: %@",contact.pic); //logs (null)
```

Can anyone suggest bullet proof code to exclude all but valid strings greater than four characters?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Are you saying that you have a case where the `NSLog` shows `(null)` and that same value ends up in your `// I have a valid string` code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not catching the case where the value is nil, have you tried including a catch for this too

```
if (contact.pic && ![contact.pic isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && contact.pic.length >= 4) {
    //I have a valid string
}
else {
    //I don't have valid string
}
```

Note that I have also made your inequality `>=` rather than `>` since your question suggests that `4` is a valid value.

Comment: If you are going to add a check to see if `contact.pic` is `nil`, make it the first check. But it's not needed. If it's `nil`, the check against `NSNull` will be false and the `!` makes that part true. So then the length will be checked. But the length will be `0` if `contact.pic` is `nil` and `0` is not `> 4` so the whole thing is false.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use following three macros in every project for `NSString` validations as required

```
#define IfNULL(original, replacement) IsNULL(original) ? replacement : original

#define IsNULL(original) original == (id)[NSNull null] || original == nil

#define IsEmpty(value) (value == (value == nil) || (id)[NSNull null] || ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && ([value isEqualToString:@""] || [value isEqualToString:@"<null>"] || [value isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || [value isEqualToString:@" "]))) ? YES : NO
```

**Usage**

```
if(!isEmpty(contact.pic)){
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Why aren't the comparisons against `nil` first?

Comment: Yes nil should be first